# Sending Command Line Arguments in Eclipse on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line-arguments

I'm using the Eclipse IDE for a Java 8 project I have started and want to send command line arguments.  I am using a Mac desktop and the way Windows runs Eclipse is a little bit different than Mac so those tutorials have not been helpful.

Does anyone know how to set a program up to read the CLOs?

Answer (score 0):

On macOS you use the `open` command from Terminal to open applications.

For Eclipse this might be:

```
open /Applications/Eclipse.app --args ...arguments...
```

If Eclipse is already running and you want to open another instance specify the `--new` option:

```
open --new /Applications/Eclipse.app --args ...arguments...
```